# in a vertical menu, if i hover each menu three columns of submenus should display using bootstrap material design

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <ul class="vertical-nav">
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <div class='column'>
                  <li class='title'>Style</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
                </div>
                 <div class='column'>
                  <li class='title'>Subject</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
                </div>
                 <div class='column'>
                  <li class='title'>Medium</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 6</a></li>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
      <img src="images/banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

it is getting like this now https://jsfiddle.net/k8wczzvd/

I want to get it as like this image[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZh6X.jpg[1]

Comment: Little update on Your code --https://jsfiddle.net/k8wczzvd/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to `show/hide` submenu using script. Check following snippet for this.

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  width: 25%;
}
.sub-menu {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 320px;
}
.vertical-nav li, .sub-menu li {
  list-style:none;
  position: relative;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover .sub-menu{
  display: block;
}
.column {
  float:left;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100px;
}
.title {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul class="vertical-nav">
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a>
            <div class='sub-menu'>
          <ul class="column">
              <li class='title'>Style</li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
             <ul class='column'>
              <li class='title'>Subject</li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
             <ul class='column'>
              <li class='title'>Medium</li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 6</a></li>
          </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```