# vertical menu with submenu in bootstrap material design

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It is getting like this now

https://jsfiddle.net/nax4ryL1/

I want to get it as like this below image

[image]
how to get it like this tabular submenu while hovering each vertical menu which should be above the banner image?

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <ul class="vertical-nav">
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a>
                <div class='sub-menu'>
              <ul class="column">
                  <li class='title'>Style</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
                 <ul class='column'>
                  <li class='title'>Subject</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
                 <ul class='column'>
                  <li class='title'>Medium</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Link 6</a></li>
              </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <img src="images/banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in a vertical menu, if i hover each menu three columns of submenus should display using bootstrap material design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108058/in-a-vertical-menu-if-i-hover-each-menu-three-columns-of-submenus-should-displa)

Comment: both are posted by me

Comment: but the solution is not found yet

Comment: Just because a solution has not been found it don't mean you should make a new question already.

Comment: then you tell the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set z-index in numeric format (NOT px)
z-index: 1;

```css
.sub-menu {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 320px;
  z-index: 1;


  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }
.vertical-nav li, .sub-menu li {
  list-style:none;
  position: relative;
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
}
.vertical-nav li:hover .sub-menu{
  display: block;
}
.column {
  float:left;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100px;
}
.title {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <ul class="vertical-nav">
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a>
            <div class='sub-menu'>
          <ul class="column">
              <li class='title'>Style</li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
             <ul class='column'>
              <li class='title'>Subject</li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
             <ul class='column'>
              <li class='title'>Medium</li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 6</a></li>
          </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```